# Read JSON from local file but error on map function

Tags: javascript, typescript, react-native, next.js

I followed a few articles on how to read json data from a local file in React and they are recommending using map function. Like https://morioh.com/p/316b1492cfda

I am getting an error

```
Property 'map' does not exist on type '{ updated: number; }'.ts(223)
```

Here is my code

```
import UpdatedFile from '../public/updated.json';

const[Updated,setUpdated]= useState("9/9/2020");

  const newdata = UpdatedFile.map((data) =>{  // This is where the error is coming
    return (
      setUpdated({map.updated})
    )
      });
```

This is how my JSON file looks like.

```
{
  "updated": 1599692605913
}
```

Any idea why its not recognizing map as a valid function?

Comment: map() is an array method....you have an object literal, not an array

Comment: I still don't get what exactly are you trying to do?
.map is a method to for arrays,   your file has a json object, not an array as in the link you're following

did you try to access UpdatedFile.updated directly?

Comment: In order for you to use map method, you need to convert the object to array. You use one of three methods: Object.keys(), Object.values(), and Object.entries().

https://www.javascripttutorial.net/object/convert-an-object-to-an-array-in-javascript/#:~:text=To%20convert%20an%20object%20to%20an%20array%20you%20use%20one,entries()%20.

Comment: @mbkfa93, thanks much yes, that made sense. Is there a good web page I can read how to know if json has an array or object. How do you know its an object and not an array?

Comment: @Sarah, It's usually the syntax
https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_json_arrays.asp

but if you're generally speaking, assuming you want to know the type of the data, you can use the 'typeof' operator, along with Array.isArray, since 'typeof' for arrays will return 'object'

You can read about typeof here -> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/typeof , and 
more about isArray here
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/isArray